# Methods ng-hide and ng-disable won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, laravel

I can't make `ng-hide` work to hide my table row with a button click. It only works if `ng-controller="FileDestroyController"` is defined alone next to ng-hide in the `table row`.

But I also need to disable my button with a button click. `ng-disable` only works if `ng-controller="FileDestroyController"` is defined next to the `span` where the buttons are. BUT if I define it here, `ng-hide` won't work but `ng-disable` will.

I can't make `ng-hide` and `ng-disable` work at the same time.

- Set cover photo = disables both buttons
- delete = hides table row

Edit

I'm using Laravel that is why there is a `@foreach` statement there and not a `ng-repeater`. There has been an issue rendering the image (thumbnail) but it isn't shown in the code. I'm just focusing on the buttons.

`ng-disable` works with my sample below.
The buttons are indented so they're easily spotted.

```
<tbody ng-controller="VideoController">
              @foreach($videos as $video)
              <tr ng-hide="deleted == true" ng-controller="FileDestroyController">     
                <td class="col-sm-2 btn_video_actions">
                        <span ng-controller="FileDestroyController" ng-init="btnPressed = false" ng-if="{{ ($log_user->profile->user_profile_cover_video != $video->media_id ? 'true': 'false') }}">
                          <button ng-disabled="btnPressed == true" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_video_actions" ng-click="coverVideo({{$video->media_id}})">
                             <span>Set Cover video</span>
                          </button>
                          <button  ng-disabled="btnPressed == true" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_video_actions" ng-click="destroyVideo({{$video->media_id}})" >
                            <span>Delete</span>
                          </button>
                        </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the `@foreach` construct. Shouldn't you be using something like `ng-repeat="video in videos"` and `videos` is an `array` defined in `VideoController`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Laravel. There has been an issue with rendering the image(thumbnail) if I use ng-repeat so I instead used @foreach of laravel since the framework is Laravel. And yes, Videos is an array that gets to be displayed in the tablerow.

Comment: You're mixing two semantic-pattern libraries; I wouldn't really recommend that. Remember, AngularJS *modifies* the DOM *after* it's loaded, but Laravel gives a rendered page; Angular might now know about these inclusions as they have been rendered outside the scope of Angular's engine.

Comment: Also `ng-controller="FileDestroyController" ` should be defined only once in the page, every time you add it to a new component, the controller is recreated again. I suggest to create  a plunkr with your problems (both `ng-repeat` and `ng-show`/`ng-disabled`) and then we will help to create a solution with angular, avoiding Laravel. Your issue described here is due to inner scopes. It is a "mistery" how the angular scopes would work with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It really was laravel that was causing the problem. I used angular's `ng-repeat` again instead of laravel's `foreach`.

It seems that angular controllers don't work with laravel's `foreach` unless defined within the same `div`.

I just made a solution for the image rendering problem. The controllers don't need to be defined multiple times anymore.